# Constraints on parameters using scipy differential evolution

Tags: python, constraints, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

I am trying to use differential evolution to optimize availability based on cost. However, I have three unknown parameters (a, b, c) here and I can define the range using bounds. However, I want to define additional constraint as a+b+c <= 10000. I am using python to do this and I tried to use an option "args" within differential evolution but it did not work. Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample.

Comment: def ahs_Ca():
        for budg in range(7000000,100000000,10000000):
            xaxis.append(budg)
            f = (0,budg)
            bounds =[f]*component 
            resultEta = differential_evolution(eta, bounds, maxiter = 4000)    This is the sample code with bounds. I need to define some constraints here. Hope this information is helpful.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Defining the constraint using differential evolution is not an appropriate solution for the problem I have described above. For this purpose, we can use Nminimize command which has dedicated option to define constraints.

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hack. I used the last example from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) and constrained the sum(x) > 4.1 (without this constraint the optimized solution is (0,0)):

```
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import numpy as np
def ackley(x):
    arg1 = -0.2 * np.sqrt(0.5 * (x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2))
    arg2 = 0.5 * (np.cos(2. * np.pi * x[0]) + np.cos(2. * np.pi * x[1]))

    if x[0]+x[1] > 4.1: #this is the constraint, where you would say a+b+c <=1000
        return -20. * np.exp(arg1) - np.exp(arg2) + 20. + np.e
    else:
        return 1000 #some high value

bounds = [(-5, 5), (-5, 5)]
result = differential_evolution(ackley, bounds)
result.x, result.fun
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I had to use a different optimization due to the complexity of my optimization problem.

Comment: More generically, `np.inf` can be returned if a constraint is violated, and it works.

Comment: I posted a proper and detailed solution, using `scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71341247/3753826